# How to use the top command in Unix to only see process using more than 10% CPU?

Tags: unix, cpu, top

I want to use top, but not see all of the processes that are using minute chunks of computing power. Can someone tell me how to use top to see things above a certain cpu % cutoff? I tried just using vanilla top that ranks processes by CPU usage and pass it through head, but it doesn't refresh: `top | head -n 15`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X `top` (which should be similar to BSD `top`), you can run `top -o cpu -n 10` to display the top 10 processes by CPU usage.

Comment: On CentOS and Ubuntu, `-n` means something different (maximum number of iterations before exiting) and `-o cpu` should be `-o %CPU`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of what you're trying to do since `top` sorts by CPU% by default so all you need is to resize your terminal window to only have the top processes showing.

The GNU top I have on my Debian has no option for this in `man top`, but you could always run something convoluted like:

```
watch  "top -bn1 | awk '{if(/^[^0-9 ]/){print}else if(\$9 >= 10){print}}' "
```

This uses `watch` which will run the specified command every two seconds (by default, change the interval with `-n`) and `gawk` to parse the output of `top` in batch mode and only print the processes using at least 10% CPU.